# ANT : JMockIt mocking is not working

Tags: java, ant, junit4, jmockit

Test cases are written using JMockIt to mock complex behavior. Mocking is working as expected when test cases are executed using eclipse.

But when test cases are executed using ANT, mocking is not working as expected since mocking mocking method throws Exception.

In Ant build script [launchJunit task](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.ant.tasks.doc/topics/tlaunchjunit.html) is used instead of junit task, to execute the Junit test cases.

As per analysis, root cause seems to be build script launches JRE to execute test cases and JRE does not have tools.jar file. I added tools.jar file in my application classpath but still problem is not solved.

Java home point to correct JDK but as per ant diagnostic tool java home is %JAVA_HOME%/jre.
Property env.JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME% correct JDK
Property java.home = %JAVA_HOME%/jre

I am getting most of the hint to solve problem for junit task but not came across any solution of launchJunit task.

Is my understanding of the problem is correct and how to resolve issue?

Comment: Getting a "The requested resource is not found" error when accessing that link. Not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed the link, but it is still completely unclear what your problem is. You've spent a lot of time writing a seven paragraph question but have managed to leave out any useful details, like what the `Exception` being thrown is, or a *simple* ant script that reproduces the problem. As such, I would not expect anybody to help you because I don't think anybody *can*, with the information you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for reply...Its from my project in company so purposefully not added any code snippest...Problem is unable to use Jmockit from Junit Test cases...Most of the ant task used in the project are from ant4eclipse library...I changed the junit task from  launchJunit to junit and things started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet your case.When i run jmockit in junit eclipse plugins, it works. But switch to the ant task, it halts in junit task, no error, either no info. So i check all the classpath and environment variable in the ant xml and eclipse junit lancher. When i make them same config, it turns to be ok! I think you can try my way, just check the classpath and variable in the two cases.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i solved this problem long time back by converting eclipse launch ant task to junit ant task which allowed me to change lot of variable but not able to solve with eclipse launch ant task..